# Generic structs in unions

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a generic vector class. While I can do something like this:

```
struct vector3 {
  union {
    struct {
      float x;
      float y;
      float z;
    };
    float v[3];
  };
};
```

I cannot do this:

```
template<int N, typename S, typename T = double>
class vec {
    union {
        T data[N];
        S;
    };
};

struct XY { REAL x, y; };
typedef vec<2, XY, REAL> Vector2;
```

because "S does not declare anything."

Is there any way to insert a generic template parameter as a member of a union? Essentially, I want to "inject" *x* and *y* fields into the vec class. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what's wrong with `T v[N]` alone? Why do you want a union to name each item also?

Comment: All this trouble just to be able to use `.y` instead of `[1]`. Is it worth it? Also, you can accomplish similar things using conversions back and forth between array-container and `struct XY`-style types.

Comment: It's probably not worth it, but I've spent so much time thinking about it that it's become more of an intellectual challenge :-)

Comment: then here's a complication for your intellectual challenge: using the union is probably going to be less efficient due to aliasing. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to name the member:

```
template<int N, typename S, typename T = double>
class vec {
    union {
        T data[N];
        S you_need_to_have_a_member_name_here;
    };
};

struct XY { REAL x, y; };
typedef vec<2, XY, REAL> Vector2;
```

But more importantly, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you want a heterogeneous container, you should do it via polymorphism. If you want a generic vector, use `std::vector`.

Also, you can't use templates to provide member names, only member types. What the above gets you will still be accessed as `Vector2::you_need_to_have_a_member_name_here.x` and `Vector2::you_need_to_have_a_member_name_here.y`.

**edit1**

OK, for what you're doing there's no really easy way. But there's a somewhat easy way (although it's pure evil).

```
#define Vec(D, X) struct Vector ## D { \
  X;  \
};

Vec(2, int x, y)
Vec(3, int x, y, z)
Vec(4, int w, x, y, z)
Vec(5, int v, w, x, y, z)
```

It's not pretty, safe, or sane, but it'll work. This is only if you really need specific member names. In general, there are safer ways if you can give up that requirement.

Comment: It's not homework. What I'm trying to accomplish is define a vector to be used for linear algebra operations. I want to define the vector generically, i.e. so that I can have an N-dimensional vector. There are lots of overloaded operators and such that I've omitted from the code snippet above to keep it short. For convenience, it would be nice if x and y were members of vec<2>, { x, y, z} members of vec<3>,  etc.

Comment: Beautiful idea with edit1, although it **would** be pretty evil :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement tuple? That is what I understand from generic vector (I'm assuming this is vector space's vector, not `std::vector`). [C++0x has this feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Tuple_types). Not sure which compiler implements it.

Comment: Ah, good point. If it is a vector (the linear algebra kind) he wants, tuple is the way to go. +1

Comment: From OP's example, it looks like vector space's vector.